# Как проверить ссылку в тексте?

Tags: python

Мне нужно сделать проверку на `https://`. Если ссылки нет в тексте, то следующий текст, если есть - пропускаю. И как в `check` добавить несколько проверочных слов?

```
check = "Подпишись"
lik = []
id1 = []
posts = src['response']['items']

for likes in posts:
    text = likes['text']
    if check in text:
        print("Это конкурс")
    else:
        lik1 = likes['likes']['count']
        lik.append(lik1)
        id = likes["id"]
        id1.append(id)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827557/how-do-you-validate-a-url-with-a-regular-expression-in-python - это нужно?

Comment: А без регулярок это возможно сделать ?

Comment: без регулярок только самое простое типа проверить, что в строке первые символы - это 'https://' - `if url[:8] == 'https://'` или писать очень большой код, который по сути и будет делать тоже что и регулярка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант решения с `'https://' in text` не такой гибкий и мощный, как с RegExp, но рабочий. В части добавления в `check` нескольких слов - можно использовать множества (`set`) с методом `intersection()` (пересечение множеств). Код не тестировал ввиду отсутствия датасета.

```
check = {"подпишись",'присоединись','запишись'} # несколько значений в множестве
lik = []
id1 = []
posts = src['response']['items']

for likes in posts:
    text = likes['text']
    if 'https://' in text: # если подстрока 'https://' есть в тексте, то обрабатываем, иначе пропускаем
        if check.intersection(text.lower().split()): # если хотя бы одно из значений множества check находится в списке, полученном из разрезанного по пробелам текста
            print("Это конкурс")
        else:
            lik1 = likes['likes']['count']
            lik.append(lik1)
            id = likes["id"]
            id1.append(id)
```

Comment: Не получается со списком !

Comment: @teamarden что именно не получается? можно на список посмотреть?